# .map is not a function in react when calling a carousel component on async props element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, carousel

I have an already working site. I am working on updating a react template by adding a carousel or image slider at the bottom of the page. The idea is to display images from a folder using a mongodb collection. I created the carousel/slider component as follows:

```
import React, { Intl } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";

const DeviceCarousel = ({ ImagesDevices }) => {
  const responsive = {
    superLargeDesktop: {
      // the naming can be any, depends on you.
      breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
      items: 5,
    },
    desktop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 2999, min: 1024 },
      items: 3,
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: { max: 1023, min: 464 },
      items: 2,
    },
    mobile: {
      breakpoint: { max: 463, min: 0 },
      items: 1,
    },
  };

  return (
    
    <div id='news'>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>News &amp; Articles</h1>
        <Carousel responsive={responsive}>
          {ImagesDevices.map((deviceimage) => {
              const imagepath =`/images/gallery/${deviceimage.filename}`;
            return (
              <div className='carouselItem'>
                  <img src={imagepath} alt='Image' />
                  <div className='caption'>
                    <div className='caption-inner'>
                      <h4 className='no-bar'>{deviceimage.caption}</h4>
                      <h5 className='no-bar'>
                        {deviceimage.copyright} 
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DeviceCarousel;
```

I then went on to call the component in my main template:

```
import Navbar from "../../components/Header";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import ArticleInfo from "../../components/ArticleInfo";

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import CompanyLink from "../../components/crossLinks/companyLink";
import ResearchGroupLink from "../../components/crossLinks/researchGroupLink";

import DeviceCarousel from "../../components/devices/DeviceCarousel";
const ImageLink = dynamic(() => import("../../components/crossLinks/imageLink"), {ssr: false});
const PublicationLink = dynamic(() => import("../../components/crossLinks/publicationLink"), {ssr: false});

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faBrain, faClock, faCheckCircle, faTimesCircle, 
         faHospitalUser, faAward, faBan, faUsers } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import Device from "../../models/Device";
import Company from "../../models/Company";
import ResearchGroup from "../../models/ResearchGroup";
import University from "../../models/University";
import Person from "../../models/Person";

import DeviceImageGallery from "../../models/DeviceImageGallery";


import dbConnect from "../../utils/dbConnect";
import Error from "next/error";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";



function getArticles(name) {
  let nameArr = name.split(" ");
  let queryString = "";
  nameArr.forEach(function (item, index) {
    queryString += item;
    if (index !== nameArr.length - 1) {
      queryString += "%20";
    }
  });
  const URL = `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=${queryString}`;
  return axios.get(URL, {
    headers: { "Zotero-API-Version": "3" },
  });
}

const DeviceTemplate = ({ errorCode, data,ImagesDevices}) => {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />;
  }
  const deviceInfo = JSON.parse(data);
  deviceInfo.researchGroupsId = JSON.parse(deviceInfo.researchGroupsId);
  deviceInfo.commercialPartnersId = JSON.parse(deviceInfo.commercialPartnersId);
  deviceInfo.authorId = JSON.parse(deviceInfo.authorId);
  deviceInfo.verifiedId = JSON.parse(deviceInfo.verifiedId);
  

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getArticles(name).then(function (result) {
      setArticles(result.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const {
    name,
    queryName,
    researchGroupsId,
    commercialPartnersId,
    status,
    implantLocation,
    numImplantedToDate,
    summary,
    background,
    videoLink,
    clinicalTrials,
    imageProcessorLocation,
    elecNumber,
    elecLayout,
    elecDiameter,
    elecPitch,
    firstPatientYear,
    fdaApprovalYear,
    ceMarkYear,
    endOfProductionYear,
    lastUpdate,
    authorId,
    verifiedId
  } = deviceInfo;

  const imagePath = `/images/logos/devices/${queryName}.jpg`;

  

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar scrollEffect={true} />
      <div id='device-profile'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row mb-4'>
            <div className='col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3'>
              <ImageLink 
                id='device-logo' 
                className='border-image'
                src={imagePath} 
                alternativeImage="/images/logos/devices/device.png" 
              />
            </div>
            <div id='device-info' class='col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9'>
              <h2>{name}</h2>
              { implantLocation && (
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBrain} size='1x' alt='implant location' />{implantLocation}</p>
              )}
              { numImplantedToDate && (
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUsers} size='1x' alt='implant location' />{numImplantedToDate} implanted</p>
              )}              
              { status == "active" && (
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheckCircle} size='1x' alt='active' />active</p>
              )}
              { status == "inactive" && (
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimesCircle} size='1x' alt='inactive' />inactive</p>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>

          { summary && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <p>{summary}</p>
            </div>
          )}

          { commercialPartnersId.length !== 0 && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Commercial Partners {queryName} {ImagesDevices}  </h3>
              <ul className='cross-links d-flex flex-wrap p-1'>
                {commercialPartnersId.map(partner => (
                  <CompanyLink
                    name={partner.name}
                    queryName={partner.queryName}
                    city={partner.city}
                    country={partner.country} />
                  ))
                }
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}

          { researchGroupsId.length !== 0 && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Academic Collaborators </h3>
              <ul className='cross-links d-flex flex-wrap p-1'>
                {researchGroupsId.map(partner => (
                  <ResearchGroupLink
                    name={partner.name}
                    queryName={partner.queryName}
                    university={partner.universityId && partner.universityId.name} />
                  ))
                }
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}


          { (firstPatientYear || fdaApprovalYear || ceMarkYear || endOfProductionYear) && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Milestones</h3>
              <ul className='milestones'>
                { firstPatientYear && (
                  <li><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHospitalUser} size='1x' alt='first patient'/>{firstPatientYear}: First patient implanted</li>
                )}
                { ceMarkYear && (
                  <li><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAward} size='1x' alt='CE mark approval'/>{ceMarkYear}: CE mark approval</li>
                )}
                { fdaApprovalYear && (
                  <li><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAward} size='1x' alt='FDA approval'/>{fdaApprovalYear}: FDA approval</li>
                )}
                { endOfProductionYear && (
                  <li><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBan} size='1x' alt='End of production'/>{endOfProductionYear}: End of production</li>
                )}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}

          { (background || videoLink) && (
            <div className='row mb-4'>
              <h3>Background</h3>
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: background }} />
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: videoLink }} />
            </div>
          )}

          { (elecNumber || elecLayout || elecDiameter || elecPitch || imageProcessorLocation) && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Device Specifications</h3>
              <ul>
                { elecNumber && (
                  <li>Number of electrodes: {elecNumber}</li>
                )}
                { elecLayout && (
                  <li>Electrode layout: {elecLayout}</li>
                )}
                { elecDiameter && (
                  <li>Electrode diameter: {elecDiameter} μm</li>
                )}
                { elecPitch && (
                  <li>Electrode pitch: {elecPitch} μm</li>
                )}
                { imageProcessorLocation && (
                  <li>Image processor location: {imageProcessorLocation}</li>
                )}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}

          { clinicalTrials.length !== 0 && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Clinical Trials </h3>
              <ul>
                { clinicalTrials.map(item => (
                  <li><a href={`xxxxxxxxxx/${item}`} target='_blank'>{item}</a></li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}

          {articles.length !== 0 && (
            <div className='row mb-3'>
              <h3>Selected Publications </h3>
              <ul className='cross-links'>
              {articles.map(article => (
                <PublicationLink
                  authors={article.data.creators}
                  title={article.data.title}
                  date={article.data.date}
                  journal={article.data.publicationTitle}
                  conference={article.data.proceedingsTitle}
                  doi={article.data.DOI}
                  issue={article.data.issue}
                  volume={article.data.volume}
                  pages={article.data.pages}
                  type={article.data.itemType} />
                ))
              }
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}

          <div className='row mb-4'>
            <ArticleInfo lastUpdate={lastUpdate} authorId={authorId} verifiedId={verifiedId}/>
            <DeviceCarousel ImagesDevices={ImagesDevices}/>
          </div>
          

        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { deviceName } }) {
  dbConnect();
  const deviceResult = await Device.findOne({
    queryName: deviceName,
    })
    .populate({ path: "researchGroupsId", model: ResearchGroup,
                select: "name university queryName",
                populate: { path: "university", model: University, select: "name" }})
    .populate({ path: "commercialPartnersId", model: Company, 
                select: "name queryName city country yearFounded yearDissolved" })
    .populate({ path: "authorId", model: Person, 
                select: "firstName preferredName lastName queryName researchGroupId",
                populate: { path: "researchGroupId", model: ResearchGroup, select: "universityId",
                            populate: { path: "universityId", model: University, select: "name" } } })
    .populate({ path: "verifiedId", model: Person, 
                select: "firstName preferredName lastName queryName researchGroupId",
                populate: { path: "researchGroupId", model: ResearchGroup, select: "universityId",
                            populate: { path: "universityId", model: University, select: "name" } } });
const thedevice=await Device.findOne({queryName:deviceName});
const iddevice=thedevice._id;

  const errorCode = deviceResult ? false : 400;
  deviceResult.researchGroupsId = JSON.stringify(deviceResult.researchGroupsId);
  deviceResult.commercialPartnersId = JSON.stringify(deviceResult.commercialPartnersId);
  deviceResult.authorId = JSON.stringify(deviceResult.authorId);
  deviceResult.verifiedId = JSON.stringify(deviceResult.verifiedId);
  deviceResult.lastUpdate = JSON.stringify(deviceResult.lastUpdate);
  //the code that we changed is below
  deviceResult._id=JSON.stringify(deviceResult._id);
  
  const deviceImages = await DeviceImageGallery.find({deviceId:deviceResult._id}).sort({order:1});
  
  //
  return {
    props: { errorCode: errorCode, data: JSON.stringify(deviceResult),ImagesDevices:JSON.stringify(deviceImages) },
  };
}

export default DeviceTemplate;
```

ImagesDevices is an array that was arrived at in the async function below through querying of the mongodb collection, however when I call

```
<DeviceCarousel ImagesDevices={ImagesDevices}/>
```

as seen in the code I am given the error that the ImagesDevices.map in the slider component(the first set of code) is not a function.  the ImagesDevices element that I arrived at from the second set of code when passed through the slider component seems to be giving this error.

[image]

I have read that this error happens when data is not in array format. I converted my ImagesDevices element into an array even though it already was. I am however still getting this error. everything was rendering fine until I made that call in my template. Any ideas on where my code is wrong? or am I calling my slider component wrong?

Comment: Put console.log(ImageDevices). If this is your last update to it - JSON.stringify(deviceImages) , then it is a string not an array.

Comment: should I do that in the props element or in the carousel component or where ? ig I do it on the carousel component I am getting a cannot read property of undefined@TusharShahi

Comment: Inside the DeviceTemplate function will do. That is where you are passing ImageDevices right?

Comment: Hi I am still getting the error, cannot map undefined when calling it in the template @TusharShahi can it be that stringifying should be removed all together.

Comment: I feel you should. But first, did you check what console.log is showing?

Comment: its not showing anything. I am simply getting the same error. I have already displayed the element before and it is an array with two elements @TusharShahi

Comment: Where have you checked the element before this? You can try removing the JSON.stringify(deviceImages). It should not be there logically. I am not sure if it will work though, since you mentioned it is not displaying anything

Comment: I have tried doing that but if I remove it says that I should only be passing serialized data through the props. @TusharShahi UPDATE: actually the stringify method was turning it into a string as you mentioned. I was able to bypass all this with JSON.parse(ImagesDevices) when passing it to the carousel component